# Multiple textbox arrays in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, controls

I am trying to generate a small program for use at my golf club

There will 1 to 4 player scores to enter on 18 holes and there will be par values and stroke index values fo all 18 holes.  There will also be better ball team scores to calculate in anothe set of textboxes.

Playing around in VBA for Access I ended up with 72 textbox controls - each with up to four event handlers.  Copy & paste and editing works fine for a trial run but I know it must be easier to have arrays for these controls - mostly for error checking that users, other than myself, do not try to enter silly things like "Four" for a score or 5.2 or -5.

Everything else is under control except all these textboxes.

I am a newbie to C# - I last programmed for real in C+ back in the 1990's and things have changed somewhat!

Not tried anything yet as I really want to be able to use controls at design time rather than having to create them each time the code runs

Comment: You can create the controls in code (dynamically) and store in array(s)/list(s). But the downside is that you will not be able to edit them visually in the designer. Maybe you should consider another kind of UI element, like a ListView/ListBox.

Comment: Sounds like you want a datagrid rather than the textboxes?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using windows forms you can usually do something simple like

```
public class MyForm{

    public MyForm(){
       InitializeComponent();
       AllTextBoxes = new []{
           myTextbox1,
           myTextbox2,
           ...
          }

    }
    private TextBox[] AllTextBoxes {get;}
```

This allow you to process all the controls in a loop, like

```
for(var i = 0; i < AllTextBoxes.Length; i++){
    var textbox = AllTextBoxes[i];
    textbox.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;

    // or use a lambda to specify arguments
    textbox.TextChanged += (o, e) => OnTextChanged(i);
}
```

You probably want some more complex way to organize boxes, like putting all boxes for the scores in a array, with the index representing something like a player.

But the better solution is to create custom user controls. If you have repeating elements, and you probably do, create a custom control with these elements, and create multiple instances of this control in your main form. This will require a bit of learning and experimentation, but it can greatly simplify your application.

Answer (score -1):

I usually create a class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const int FIRST_BOX_TOP = 50;
        const int FIRST_BOX_LEFT = 50;
        const int LABEL_HEIGHT = 20;
        const int BOX_HEIGTH = 20;
        const int BOX_WIDTH = 20;
        const int HEIGHT_SPACE = 10;
        const int WIDTH_SPACE = 10;
        const int HOLE_HEIGTH_SPACE = 40;
        const int HOLE_WIDTH_SPACE = 100;

        public Hole[] course = new Hole[18];
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int holeNumber = 0;
            for (int row = 0; row < 2; row++)
            {
                for (int col = 0; col < 9; col++)
                {
                    Label label = new Label();
                    label.Height = LABEL_HEIGHT;
                    label.Text = "Hole " + (holeNumber + 1);
                    label.Top = FIRST_BOX_TOP + row * (HOLE_HEIGTH_SPACE + (4 * (BOX_HEIGTH + HEIGHT_SPACE)));
                    label.Left = FIRST_BOX_LEFT + (col * (HOLE_WIDTH_SPACE + WIDTH_SPACE));
                    this.Controls.Add(label);
                    Hole hole = new Hole();
                    for (int box = 0; box < 4; box++)
                    {
                        TextBox tbox = new TextBox();
                        tbox.Top = FIRST_BOX_TOP + LABEL_HEIGHT + row * (HOLE_HEIGTH_SPACE + HEIGHT_SPACE + (4 * ( BOX_HEIGTH + HEIGHT_SPACE))) + (box * (BOX_HEIGTH + HEIGHT_SPACE));
                        tbox.Left = FIRST_BOX_LEFT + (col * (HOLE_WIDTH_SPACE + WIDTH_SPACE));
                        tbox.Height = BOX_HEIGTH;
                        tbox.Width = BOX_WIDTH;
                        this.Controls.Add(tbox);

                        course[holeNumber] = hole;

                        hole.events[box] = tbox;
                    }
                    holeNumber++;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public class Hole
    {
        public TextBox[] events = new TextBox[4];
    }


}
```

Comment: I updated answer to include full code.